# redux-saga call does not yield when promise resolves. What could be going on here?

Tags: redux-saga

This is my code:

```
console.log('call will be made');
const { Status, CallbackUrl } = yield call(fetchUrl, getSsoEndpointUrl(), options);
console.log('call has yielded');

function fetchUrl(url: string, options: RequestInit) {
    return fetch(url, options)
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((data: SsoServerReponse) => {
            console.log('promise resolves', data.data);
            return data.data;
        });
}
```

I get the following log output:

```
sagas.ts call will be made
sagas.ts promise resolves {Status: 200, CallbackUrl: "..."}
```

I don't understand what could be going wrong here. The `fetchUrl` promise resolves. Why does `console.log('call has yielded')` never happen?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had the following lines somewhere else in the code:

```
yield take(LOCATION_CHANGE);
yield cancel(ssoSignInWatcher);
```

In other words, the problem was pretty impossible to guess from reading my question. I am closing the question.